# Sed and Regular Expressions

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I've got a problem with some regular expression in `sed`.

I want to change a line in my file, so I did it like that:

`sed -i '3s/.*/my new text in file/' file.txt`.

This extension is looking for 3rd line in a file and change it.

This solution isn't good but I don't know how to build a good regular extension. Let's say that I am looking for the word 'Host' in some file. How to build a good regular extension?

I have tried the following:

`sed -e '<\H...s>\ /my new text in file/' file.txt`'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you have found the word, would you want to replace the hole line, or just the word?

Comment: I wanna replace all line. Old line will be delete, and new will be add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^.*[[:<:]]Host[[:>:]].*$/replacement text/' file.txt
```

The above will replace every line in the file `file.txt` that contains the word `Host` with the string `replacement text`. The result will be given on standard output.

The `[[:<:]]` is a zero-length pattern that matches at the beginning of a word. Similarly, `[[:>:]]` will match at the end of a word.  This means that the above substitution will *not* replace a line with the word `Hostname` or `xHost` on it (unless the word `Host` appears elsewhere on the line).

Comment: `sed -e expression # 1 sign 68: Wrong name of a character class`<-- this shows  when i use your extension.

Comment: @SanHolo Then try using the older syntax `\<` in place of `[[:<:]]` and `\>` in place of `[[:>:]]`.

Comment: Now extensions doesnt show error, but didnt change anythink.

Comment: @SanHolo It may be enough to just use `'s/^.*Host.*$/replacement text/'` then. It's difficult for me to know, because you didn't supply an example of the input.

Comment: @Kusalananda Wouldn't this work to change only the word `Host`: `sed 's/.* Host .*/replacement/'`?

Comment: @maulinglawns It wouldn't change only the word, but yes, if `Host` is surrounded by spaces in the input, that would work, but not if you want to also match e.g. `Host:` (word boundary between `Host` and `:`).

Comment: @SanHolo What `sed` are you actually using? What does `sed --version` output? What Unix are you on?

Comment: @Kusalananda Good point, gotcha!

Comment: @SanHolo Also, does "didn't change anything" mean it didn't change anything _in the original file__? No, it wouldn't have. For that, use the `-i` flag with `sed` or redirect the output to a new file and then replace the original file with that.

Comment: `sed -i 's/^.*Hosts*$/replacement text/' filename` Now its working perfect this extension searching word Host replace it and save the file. It's exactly what I wanted to do. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and sed 4.2.2

Comment: @SanHolo Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the
answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Although almost no-one seems to use it, `sed` provides a `c` (change) command for whole-line replacement:

> ```
> c\ 
> text
>
>     Delete the lines matching the address or address-range, and 
>     output the lines of text which follow this command.
> ```

So for example you could use

```
sed '/\bHost\b/c\                      
my new text
' file
```

to change lines containing whole-word `Host` to `my new text`. The `\b` sequence represents a word boundary so it will exclude partial matches like `Hostname` - in GNU sed, you can use `\<` and `\>` instead i.e. `\<Host\>` and you can also put the new text on a single line:

```
sed '/\<Host\>/cmy new text' hostfile
```

which seems to be what you were aiming for in your expression - you just missed the actual `c` command and got the word boundary specifiers backwards i.e. `<\. . .>\` in place of `\<. . .\>`

Comment: The issue with the `c` command (and `a` and `i`) is that they take the text on the next line of input, which is always a bit of a hassle (unless you're using GNU `sed`, probably).